# Application of Jensen's formula to show a special bound

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be a holomorphic function defined in a neighborhood of the closed unit disc 
$\bar D$. satisfying $f(\frac{1}{3}) = f(- \frac{1}{3})=0$. Prove that $|f(0)| \leq \frac{1}{9}sup_{D}|f|$. By Jesen's formula $log|f(0)| = \sum_{l=1}^{n}log|z_l|+ \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi}log|f(e^{i\theta})|d\theta$. Then the conclusion is immediate if $\frac{1}{3}$ and $-\frac{1}{3}$ are the only zeros of $f$. How should I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the fact that $\log |z_l| \leq 0$ for all $l$ except the one's corresponding to $\frac 1 3 $ and $-\frac 1 3 $: $\log |f(0)| \leq 2\log \frac 1 3+\frac 1 {2\pi } \int_0^{2\pi } log M \, d\theta$ where $M=\sup \{|f(z)|:|z|<1\}$. Hence $\log |f(0)| \leq -2\log 3 + \log M$ . Take exponentials to get $|f(0)| \leq \frac 1 9 M$. Note that $|f(e^{i\theta})| \leq M$ by continuity.

Comment: Sorry, I missed one coefficient.

Comment: Can you be more specific